# how 물음 come from 묻다?

Tags: grammar

as far as I know,in korean,if you want to turn a verb into noun,you just add one amongst 기,음 and 이 to that verb.
for example,if you want to turn 듣다 into noun,you can just remove 다 and add 기 to it,like 듣기.
but why this principle don't apply to 묻다?I thought Nominalization of 묻다 is 묻기?

Answer (score 1):

Because of vowels.

More specifically, 묻- becomes 물- in front of endings that start with vowels. It is a [ㄷ irregular verb](https://www.howtostudykorean.com/unit1/unit-1-lessons-1-8/unit-1-lesson-7/).

Thus 묻 takes -습니다 (not -ㅂ니다) and remains as 묻, because the following ㅅ is a consonant. This is also the reason 묻기 retains 묻; ㄱ is a consonant.

-음 on the other hand starts with a vowel, and so 묻- becomes 물-.
This is also the case with -어, thus 물어, and also 물어요. Not *묻어.

Comment: thank your answer,but are there any source to this usage?I want to learn further about it

Comment: Added a link for you.